# Regular expression - any text to URL friendly one

Tags: php, regex, friendly-url

PHP regular expression script to remove anything that is not a alphabetical letter or number 0 to 9 and replace space to a hyphen - change to lowercase make sure there is only one hyphen - between words no -- or --- etc.

For example:

Example: The quick brown fox jumped
Result: the-quick-brown-fox-jumped

Example: The quick brown fox jumped!
Result: the-quick-brown-fox-jumped

Example: The quick brown fox - jumped!
Result: the-quick-brown-fox-jumped

Example: The quick ~`!@#$%^ &*()_+= ------- brown {}|][ :"'; <>?.,/ fox - jumped!
Result: the-quick-brown-fox-jumped

Example: The quick 1234567890 ~`!@#$%^ &*()_+= ------- brown {}|][ :"'; <>?.,/ fox - jumped!
Result: the-quick-1234567890-brown-fox-jumped

---

Anybody have idea for the regular expression?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to leave hyphens when they are directly between words (e. g. "some-thing" should not translate to "something") and other special cases.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since you seem to want all sequences of non-alphanumeric characters being replaced by a single hyphen, you can use this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $str);
```

But this can result in leading or trailing hyphens that can be removed with [`trim`](http://php.net/trim):

```
$str = trim($str, '-');
```

And to convert the result into lowercase, use [`strtolower`](http://php.net/strtolower):

```
$str = strtolower($str);
```

So all together:

```
$str = strtolower($str);
$str = trim($str, '-');
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '-', $str);
```

Or in a compact one-liner:

```
$str = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $str), '-'));
```

Comment: I think a better alternative is to first replace whitespace, then non-whitespace / non-alphanumeric. In many cases the non-whitespace, non-alphanumeric characters shouldn't be dashes. Ie: "Women's Night" would be "women-s-night".

I would first replace whitespace (`/\s+/`) with dashes, then replace all else (`/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/`) with an empty string. You can omit the trim as well.

Comment: Edit to above: You'll need to add a dash to the second replacement: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/`

Comment: Be aware that this answer does not account for any diacritics, "St. Lücie-Pétêrès" will become "st-l-cie-p-t-r-s", where you would reasonably expect "st-lucie-peteres".

Comment: @gabssnake You could transliterate those characters first.

Answer (score 19):

I was just working with something similar, and I came up with this little piece of code, it also contemplates the use of latin characters.

This is the sample string:

`$str = 'El veloz murciélago hindú comía fe<!>&@#$%&!"#%&?¡?*liz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña ¨^;.-|°¬tocaba el saxofón detrás del palenque de paja';`

First I convert the string to htmlentities just to make it easier to use later.

`$friendlyURL = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", false);`

Then I replace latin characters with their corresponding ascii characters (`á` becomes `a`, `Ü` becomes `U`, and so on):

`$friendlyURL = preg_replace('/&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|circ|lig|grave|ring|tilde|uml|cedil|caron);/i','\1',$friendlyURL);`

Then I convert the string back from html entities to symbols, again for easier use later.

`$friendlyURL = html_entity_decode($friendlyURL,ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");`

Next I replace all non alphanumeric characters into hyphens.

`$friendlyURL = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/i', '-', $friendlyURL);`

I remove extra hyphens inside the string:

`$friendlyURL = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $friendlyURL);`

I remove leading and trailing hyphens:

`$friendlyURL = trim($friendlyURL, '-');`

And finally convert all into lowercase:

`$friendlyURL = strtolower($friendlyURL);`

All together:

```
function friendlyUrl ($str = '') {

    $friendlyURL = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", false); 
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|circ|lig|grave|ring|tilde|uml|cedil|caron);/i','\1',$friendlyURL);
    $friendlyURL = html_entity_decode($friendlyURL,ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); 
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/i', '-', $friendlyURL);
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $friendlyURL);
    $friendlyURL = trim($friendlyURL, '-');
    $friendlyURL = strtolower($friendlyURL);
    return $friendlyURL;

}
```

Test:

```
$str = 'El veloz murciélago hindú comía fe<!>&@#$%&!"#%&-?¡?*-liz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña ¨^`;.-|°¬tocaba el saxofón detrás del palenque de paja';

echo friendlyUrl($str);
```

Outcome:

```
el-veloz-murcielago-hindu-comia-fe-liz-cardillo-y-kiwi-la-ciguena-tocaba-el-saxofon-detras-del-palenque-de-paja
```

I guess Gumbo's answer fits your problem better, and it's a shorter code, but I thought it would be useful for others.

Cheers,
Adriana

Comment: Hi @AdrianaVillafañe, I tried with "Plâtrerie" and it outputs "pl-trerie"

Comment: @gabssnake , I'm sorry to reply so late. I edited the code to include your example. It should work after changing the second sentence inside the function to `$friendlyURL = preg_replace('/&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|circ|lig|grave|ring|tilde|uml|cedil|caron);/i','\1',$friendlyURL);` (added `|circ`). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

In a function:

```
function sanitize_text_for_urls ($str) 
{
    return trim( strtolower( preg_replace(
        array('/[^a-z0-9-\s]/ui', '/\s/', '/-+/'),
        array('', '-', '-'),
        iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str) )), '-');
}
```

What it does:

```
// Solve accents and diacritics
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);

// Leave only alphanumeric (respect existing hyphens)
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-\s]/ui', '', $str);

// Turn spaces to hyphens
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $str);

// Remove duplicate hyphens
$str = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $str);

// Remove trailing hyphens
$str = trim($str, '-');

// Turn to lowercase
$str = strtolower($str);
```

Note:
You can combine multiple `preg_replace` by passing an array. See the function at the top.

For example:

```
// Électricité, plâtrerie    -->  electricite-platrerie
// St. Lücie-Pétêrès         -->  st-lucie-peteres
// -Façade- & gros œuvre     -->  facade-gros-oeuvre

// _-Thè quîck ~`!@#&$%^ &*()_+= ---{}|][ :"; <>?.,/ fóx - jümpëd_-
// the-quick-fox-jumped
```

EDIT: added "/u" at the end of the regex to use UTF8
EDIT: accounted for duplicated and leading/trailing hyphens, thanks to @LuBre

Comment: I think it is the best solution so far.

Comment: Nice one, I'd just add `$str = preg_replace('/--+/', '-', $str )` to remove any possible consecutive spaces. Example: `hello-how---are-you` will be converted into `hello-how-are-you`.

Comment: Thanks @LuBre, I incorporated your feedback

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this for filenames in PHP, the answer by Gumbo would be

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]+/', '-', $str);
$str = trim($str, '-');
$str = strtolower($str);
```

Added a period for file names and it's `strtolower()`, not `strtolowercase()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '-', $str);
```