# strip out all strange characters of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to create a slug so I would like to strip out every strange character. The only thing the slug should contain is lowercase letters and underscores. Is there a way to check for strange characters and filter it out the string? everything that is not a character or underscore should be deleted

this is what I have:

```
if(!preg_match_all('/[a-z]/')):
    $output = preg_replace("/ ... euhm ... /", "", $slug2);
else:
    $output = $slug2;
endif;
```

I should go from this: **Create a 3D Ribbon Wrap-Around Effect (Plus a Free PSD!)**

to this: **create_a_3d_ribbon_wrap_around_effect_plus_a_free_psd**

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to "remove all characters but this, this, and this"; I think that fits your case.

Comment: So you also want to translate spaces into underscores?  And numbers are also ok?  Your example and your description do not match up.

Comment: There are 1908 lowercase letters, of which your  `[a-z]` comprises merely a hairsbreadth more than 1⅓%.

Comment: This is a duplicate of possibly many other questions. Here are some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051889/regular-expression-any-text-to-url-friendly-one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432463/how-do-i-sanitize-title-uris, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984983/php-code-to-generate-safe-url, etc.

Comment: @cdhowie of course it does not match, that's why I'm posting the question.

Comment: @Gumbo ah ok sorry about that, it was 1 am when I asked the question, I was a bit tired :) but I upvoted your anwser, I'll make sure to have al look next time

Comment: @everyone: I was already using strtolower but because that was not the problem I didn't post it in the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$slug = strtolower($slug);
$slug = str_replace(" ", "_", $slug);
$slug = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_]/", "", $slug);
```

Comment: I’m afraid you’ve forgotten one thousand eight hundred and eighty-two lowercase letters besides the those quaint 1960sish *a-z*.  `ˋunichars -a '\p{Lower}' '[^a-z]'  | wc -lˋ == 1882`

Comment: Based on the OP's example, this looks like it will be used for slugs in a URL.  And Unicode characters look *ugly* in URLs, so I doubt the OP wants to keep them.

Comment: Agreed. But interesting fact that there are more than latin, cyrillic and greek. ;)

Comment: `[^a-z0-9_]` could be sensibly reduced to `\W`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the initial match. You can do an unconditional search-and-replace. If there's nothing to replace, no big deal. Here it is as one big chain of function calls:

```
$slug = trim(preg_replace('/[\W_]+/', '_', strtolower($slug)), '_');
```

Or split out into separate lines:

```
$slug = strlower($slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/[\W_]+/', '_', $slug);
$slug = trim($slug, '_');
```

Explanation:

1. Convert uppercase to lowercase with `strtolower`.
2. Search for `\W` and `_`. A "word" character is a letter, digit, or underscore. A "non-word" character is the opposite of that, i.e. whitespace, punctuation, and control characters. `\W` matches "non-word" characters.
3. Replace those bad characters with underscores. If there's more than one in a row they'll all get replaced by a single underscore.
4. Trim underscores from the beginning and end of the string.

The code's on the complicated side because there are several tricky cases it needs to handle:

- Bad characters on the ends need to be deleted, not converted to underscores. For example, the `!)` in your example.
- We want `foo_-_bar` to turn into `foo_bar`, not `foo___bar`. Underscores should be collapsed, basically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$slug = preg_replace("[^a-z_]", "", $slug);
```

Comment: You forgot almost two thousand lowercase letters.